# How do I "Unit Test" in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing

So I have this method in my project:

```
public static String MD5Hash(string TextToHash)
{
    if ((TextToHash == null) || (TextToHash.Length == 0))
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }

    MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] textToHash = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(TextToHash);
    byte[] result = md5.ComputeHash(textToHash);
    return System.BitConverter.ToString(result);

}
```

And I've tried testing like this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using BugMon;

namespace BugMonTesting
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            string pwd = "Password";
            string expected = "DC-64-7E-B6-5E-67-11-E1-55-37-52-18-21-2B-39-64";
            frmLogIn.MD5Hash(pwd);
            Assert.AreEqual(pwd, expected);
        }
    }
}
```

But the string pwd does not seem to be passing through the Method when I run the test and stays as "Password".

What am I doing wrong?

Sorry if this is obvious but I've never had to use these tests before.

Comment: Your question isn't really about unit tests at all.

Comment: try out http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for questions like this. You'll get some additional feedback on your work.

Comment: @AndyDangerGagne nope, this question is off-topic for Code Review. Please [Be Careful when recommending Code Review to askers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers) in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're never doing anything with the return value from MD5Hash.

Try this:

```
string hash = frmLogIn.MD5Hash(pwd);
Assert.AreEqual(hash, expected);
```

Note that this will only work if MD5Hash returns a string formatted like the `expected` variable.

Comment: Sweet! Worked straight away, too simple for me to notice... Thank you!

Comment: Please do not advise people to override existing variables with a new value. This is a very poor coding style.

Comment: @DavidArno, good point.

Comment: Thanks both, now changed it to store the hashed vale in a a new, unused variable